# What state is the most friendly to consumers of long term care insurance?

Tags: united-states, insurance

Some states in the U.S. allow for the insurance company to raise the premiums on insured customers.  Which states are the most consumer-friendly for long-term care insurance?

By consumer-friendly, I mean "overall favorable to the insured."  Some states allow large premium rate hikes to happen immediately.  Some states offer market-protection that gives consumers excellent options to lock in an affordable rate.

Comment: What do you mean by "consumer-friendly"? Are you asking about a characteristic of insurance laws?

Comment: Pushing the definition of *consumer-friendly* to *"overall favorable to the insured* is just layering the vagueness further. Insurance policies are not identical in coverage, benefits, exceptions, or accessibility to customers; the changes possible under different laws make it even further impossible to compare the value of different policies and their costs in a universal objective way.